# Using open(QIODevice::WriteOnly) erases my file content

Tags: c++, xml, qt, readfile

I have a method which allows me to edit an XML file.

```
void ParserXML::writeFile(std::string path)
{
    QFile xmlFile(path.c_str());
    xmlFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    m_XMLtree.setContent(&xmlFile);
    xmlFile.close();
}
```

But I found that it opens my file (through the path), and erases all the content of this one.

Can someone explain why?

Comment: Try to open the file with `xmlFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append);`

Comment: Your method works. Thank you